# Javascript Concatenação entre Arrays

Tags: javascript

Olá, como faço para dividir um array e colocar de 3 em 3 dentro de outro?

Tenho um array:

```
aux_zip ["Cafe","feijao","frango","batata","pao","miojo","laranja","mouse","teclado];
```

quero concatenar desta forma:

```
zip ["Cafefeijaofrango","batatapaomiojo,"laranjamouseteclado];
```

De modo que ele pegue a cada 3 do outro ele faz 1 nesse.

Estou a 2 dias quebrando a cabeça com isso, poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar as respostas já existentes ao problema original com uma solução diferente, coloco aqui uma utilizando `map`, `join` e `split`.

Será mais curta a nível de código mas provavelmente menos eficiente:

```js
const aux_zip =  ["Cafe","feijao","frango","batata","pao","miojo","laranja","mouse","teclado"];

//colocar um separador _ antes de cada elemento múltiplo de 3
const mapeado = aux_zip.map((v,i) => (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) ? ("_" + v) : v);

//juntar tudo e dividir pelo separador colocado anteriormente
let resultado = mapeado.join('').split('_');

console.log(resultado);
```

Ou numa linha só com:

```
aux_zip.map((v,i) => (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) ? ("_" + v) : v).join('').split('_');
```

Comment: 1 pelo code golf!

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar um loop para ir inserindo sub arrays com o comprimento certo.
Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
const max = 3;
const array = ["Cafe", "feijao", "frango", "batata", "pao", "miojo", "laranja", "mouse", "teclado"];

let temp = null;
let arr = [];
let novaArray = [arr];
while (temp = array.shift()) {
  arr.push(temp);
  if (arr.length == max && array.length > 0) {
    arr = [];
    novaArray.push(arr);
  }
}

console.log(novaArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve percorrer o vetor armazenando os valores de 3 em 3 e atribuindo eles a um novo vetor.

```js
var comida = ["Cafe","feijao","frango","batata","pao","miojo","laranja","mouse","teclado", "ovo"];

//Variavel onde armazenarei os valores de 3 em 3.
var mistura = ""; 

//Vetor onde adiconarei os valores armazenados.
var arrayMistura = [];

//Armazeno o resto da divisão do vetor comida por 3.
var modComida = comida.length % 3;

for(i=0;i<comida.length;i++){      //Percorro o primeiro vetor.
  mistura = mistura + comida[i];   //concateno o valor dos itens
  if( (i+1) % 3 == 0){ //Se o resto da divisão por 3 for zero
   arrayMistura.push(mistura); //Adiciono os valores ao vetor
   mistura = ""; //limpo a variavel com os itens
  } 
}

//Se o resto da divisão for igual a 1 ou 2 significa que ainda a valores para armazenarmos no arrayMistura.
if( modComida == 2){
    mistura = comida[comida.length-2] + comida[comida.length-1];
}else if(modComida == 1){
  mistura = comida[comida.length-1];
}
arrayMistura.push(mistura);

console.log(arrayMistura); //Exibo resultado no console.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Só q se eu adicionar um outro valor ele não coloca no arrayMistura, eu teria que adicionar 3 para que ele reconhecesse, como eu faria para ele guardar 1 também?

Comment: Não compreendi a sua dúvida, pode me explicar novamente?

Comment: Se você adicionar o elemento "ovo" no array var comida = ["Cafe","feijao","frango","batata","pao","miojo","laranja","mouse","teclado","ovo"]; ele não aparece no arrayMistura.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer assim também:

```
const arr = ["Cafe", "feijao", "frango", "batata", "pao", "miojo", "laranja", "mouse", "teclado", "ovo"];
const max = 3;
let mistura = [];
let temp = '';

const chegouNoLimite = (index) => {
    return ((index % max) == 0);
}

const naoVaiCompletarOMax = (index) => {
    return ((index + max) > (arr.length+1)) && !temp
}

arr.forEach((comida, idx) => {
    idx++; //usar index iniciando em 1

    if (chegouNoLimite(idx)) { // contou 3
        mistura.push(temp += comida);
        temp = ''
    } else if ( naoVaiCompletarOMax(idx) ) { //não vai chegar a 3
            mistura.push(comida);
    } else { //vai chegar em 3 mas ainda não é 3
            temp += comida;
    }
});

console.log(mistura);
```